# How to use Levenshtein function in MySQL to find articles with similar titles

Tags: mysql, levenshtein-distance

So I want to be able to find similar articles based on their titles and I found out about Levenshtein. I'm going to post the function below. So my question is, how can I use this function? I think it is just for finding single words but in my case I need it to find whole sentences in the form of titles. Is levenshtein even the thing I need? My website is developed in php if it's worth mentioning. Maybe there is some php library that you could suggest.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
DECLARE s1_char CHAR;
-- max strlen=255
DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);
SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0;
IF s1 = s2 THEN
RETURN 0;
ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN
RETURN s2_len;
ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN
RETURN s1_len;
ELSE
WHILE j <= s2_len DO
SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1;
END WHILE;
WHILE i <= s1_len DO
SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1;
WHILE j <= s2_len DO
SET c = c + 1;
IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN
SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1;
END IF;
SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost;
IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
IF c > c_temp THEN
SET c = c_temp;
END IF;
SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
END WHILE;
SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END IF;
RETURN c;
END
```

Comment: I would think you would use FULL TEXT searching for this, personally. It will ignore order and return a relevance score based on the input versus the field.

Comment: Can you share some of these sentences and what you are comparing, or what you expect match?

Answer (score 0):

It will be incredibly expensive for a large table, but you can self-join the table to find similar titles:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.title
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.id != t2.id AND levenshtein(t1.title, t2.title) < 10
WHERE t1.id = :selected_id
```

Replace `10` with how close the titles need to be to each other -- lower numbers are closer.

Comment: This seems to be working but the lower `< 10` is, the slower the query. Is this normal? Also, I want to add a `where` clause so I can find articles related to the one the user is reading. How can I do this?

Comment: I've updated the answer for just finding titles close to a specific ID.

Comment: I don't think it's working anymore. It returns all rows in order by id..

Comment: Not sure why. Make sure you have all the correct `t1` and `t2` aliases.